# Regex capturing groups within logical OR

Tags: java, regex

I have a set of strings I need to parse and extract values from. They look like:

```
    /apple/1212d3fe 
    /cat/23224a2f4 
    /auto/445478eefd
    /somethingelse/1234fded
```

It should match only apple, cat and auto. The output I expect is:

```
1212, d3fe
23224, a2f4
445478, eefd
null
```

I need to come up with a regex capturing groups to do the same. I am able to extract the second part but not the first one. The closest I came up with is:

```
String r2 = "^/(apple/[0-9]{4}|cat/[0-9]{5}|auto/[0-9]{6})([a-f0-9]{4})$";
System.out.println(r2);

Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(r2);

Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher("/apple/2323efff");
if (matcher2.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher2.group(1));
  System.out.println(matcher2.group(2));
}
```

---

#### UPDATED QUESTION:

I have a set of strings I need to parse and extract values from. They look like:

```
    /apple/1212d3fe 
    /cat/23e24a2f4 
    /auto/df5478eefd
    /somethingelse/1234fded
```

It should match only apple, cat and auto. The output I expect is the everything after the 2nd '/' split as follows: 4 characters if 'apple', 5 characters if 'cat' and 6 characters if 'auto' like:

```
1212, d3fe
23e24, a2f4
df5478, eefd
null
```

I need to come up with a regex capturing groups to do the same. I am able to extract the second part but not the first one. The closest I came up with is:

```
String r2 = "^/(apple/[0-9]{4}|cat/[0-9]{5}|auto/[0-9]{6})([a-f0-9]{4})$";
System.out.println(r2);

Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(r2);

Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher("/apple/2323efff");
if (matcher2.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher2.group(1));
  System.out.println(matcher2.group(2));
}
```

---

I can do it without the regex OR(|) but it breaks when I include it. Any help with the right regex?

Comment: Are there only numbers in the first group after the word?

Comment: It matches [a-f0-9]

Comment: You could try the regex I wrote [here](https://regex101.com/r/JhV2os/2)

Comment: @SomeDude Sorry I missed to provide the constraint. I need to match only apple,cat and auto.

Comment: I think you should clarify if you want to match exactly 4 length string after apple, 5 length after cat and 6 length after auto, otherwise all anwsers here will be incorrect as I see until now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated Answer:

As per your updated question you can use this regex based on lookbehind assertions:

```
/((?<=apple/).{4}|(?<=cat/).{5}|(?<=auto/).{6})(.+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ikwSm3/3)

- This regex uses 2 capture groups after matching `/`
- In 1st group we have 3 lookbehind conditions with alternations.
- `(?<=apple/).{4}` makes sure that we match 4 characters that have `apple/` on left hand side. Likewise we match 5 and 6 character strings that have `cat/` and `/auto/`.
- In 2nd capture group we match remaining characters before end of line.

Comment: Thank you. But I updated my question. There is no guarantee that only numbers appear after the 2nd '/'

Comment: Check my updated answer. Also it is best to describe actual problem upfront rather than making major changes after many answers have been posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last group to have exactly 4 digits you can use this regex:

```
/(apple|cat|auto)/([0-9a-f]+)([0-9a-f]{4})
```

Here is a working example:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("/apple/1212d3fe", "/cat/23224a2f4", "/auto/445478eefd");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/(apple|cat|auto)/([0-9a-f]+)([0-9a-f]{4})");
for (String string : strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

If you want for digits after `apple`, 5 after `cat` and 6 after `auto` you can split your algorithm in 2 parts:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("/apple/1212d3fe", "/cat/23224a2f4", "/auto/445478eefd", "/some/445478eefd");
Pattern firstPattern = Pattern.compile("/(apple|cat|auto)/([0-9a-f]+)");
for (String string : strings) {
    Matcher firstMatcher = firstPattern.matcher(string);
    if (firstMatcher.find()) {
        String first = firstMatcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(first);
        int length = getLength(first);
        Pattern secondPattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9a-f]{" + length + "})([0-9a-f]{4})");
        Matcher secondMatcher = secondPattern.matcher(string);
        if (secondMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(secondMatcher.group(1));
            System.out.println(secondMatcher.group(2));
        }
    }
}

private static int getLength(String key) {
    switch (key) {
        case "apple":
            return 4;
        case "cat":
            return 5;
        case "auto":
            return 6;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("key not allowed");
}
```

Comment: I should match only "apple", "cat" and "auto"

Comment: @falcon You can just use `/(apple|cat|auto)/(\\d+)([a-f0-9]+)` to match that. Updated my answer.

Comment: @anubhava yes, that are the groups 2 and 3

Comment: @anubhava now I got it, I did not thought so. That is not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex `\/[apple|auto|cat]+\/(\d*)(.*)`, See [here](https://regex101.com/r/JhV2os/3)